# Reading in a file - java.io.FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, android, file-io, embedded-resource, filenotfoundexception

```
public void loadFile(int level){

    try {
                //Create new file
                levelFile = new File("assets/levels.txt");
                fis = new FileInputStream(levelFile);
                isr = new InputStreamReader(fis);    
                reader = new BufferedReader(isr);

                //Code to read the file goes here
```

Using this code, however, I keep getting the above error (`java.io.FileNotFoundException`).

The file definitely exists in my Assets folder and has the correct name.  I've found a couple of similar questions on here and have tried various things including refreshing the project, cleaning the project, using `"levels.txt"` instead of `"assets/levels.txt"` but I keep getting this error.

Any ideas why?

Comment: The path is not what you think it is. Have you tried debugging?

Comment: Are these resources supplied by you or the user?  If by you, access them as an [tag:embedded-resource] by `URL`.  If the user, offer them a [`JFileChooser`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html).

Comment: Maybe you should know what current work directory is at first. System.out.println("Working Directory = " + System.getProperty("user.dir"));

Comment: @AndrewThompson This is s a file that is supplied by me.  It contains level layout information for my game which is exported from a little level creator / editor that I wrote using swing

Comment: And once again a downvote with no comment as to why.  This helps nobody.

Comment: Giving you an upvote to negate it. Sorry for the bad apples of the community.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because you're dealing with outside the package, `getResource()` will be the best solution for your problem:

```
URL url = getClass().getResource("/assets/levels.txt");
File f = new File(url.toURI());
//....
```

Or you can directly get the input stream using `getResourceAsStream()` method :

```
InputStream  is= getClass().getResourceAsStream("/assets/levels.txt");
isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
```

It's better since you don't have to use *FileInputStream*.

Note that `URISyntaxException` must be caught with `FileNotFoundException` or declared to be thrown.

Comment: There is little point in converting the `URL` to a `File`.  Most methods/constructors that will accept a `File` will also accept an `URL`.

Answer (score 6):

In an Android project, the right way to read the content of asset files is by using the `AssetManager`. Asset files are the files you put in the `assets/` folder of your Android project. This is mentioned briefly in the sidebar on the [Accessing Resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html) page in the Android docs.

In particular, you can open the file `assets/levels.txt` and create a `BufferedReader` like this:

```
InputStream stream = context.getAssets().open("levels.txt");
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(stream));
```

Notice that the argument of the `open` call is simply `levels.txt`, not `assets/levels.txt`.

For more details see the [full docs of AssetManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html#open%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: Hi @Jabos yes this is an Android project.  Basically what I've done is, write a level editor in Java/Swing. This outputs level layout information to a text file which I put in my assets folder and then run the app on my tablet / handset.  Is this the correct way of doing this?  If I use inputStream as you've indicated in the last part of your answer, it doesn't seem to work how would I integrate this line into my code?  Do I use it instead of file levelFile = new file?  Thanks! :-)

Comment: @Zippy see my updated answer. This is the right way to read asset file content in an Android project.

Comment: Thank you for the answer @janos, for some reason I had trouble with this, so I used Azad's similar answer.  Thanks :-)

Comment: @Zippy I amended my answer to be really specific. This is the right way of doing this, and I've never had a problem with it. If you have trouble with this method, then I you must be doing something wrong. You should fix *that*, rather than choosing a less clean solution.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, as it is the proper Android way of reading local files.